# Plotly - Using "secondary_y" attribute with a list of traces?

Tags: python, plotly

So I have some `traces` that are in a list `data`. I then add them to my figure as follows:

```
data = [trace1,trace2] 
fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
```

However, I would like to add a secondary axis on one of my traces, and I found [this](https://plot.ly/python/multiple-axes/) method:

```
fig.add_trace( trace, secondary_y=True) 
fig.update_yaxes(title_text='Second Y-axis',secondary_y=True)
```

However, how would I do this in a list of traces? Or is it just impossible to use this `secondary_y` method and will have to use something else like explicitly adding an axis `y1,y2` to the traces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `update_traces` method of a plotly Figure and its selector attribute to select a specific trace, like in the example below

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Create figure with secondary y-axis
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
traces = [go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[3, 4], name='one'),
          go.Bar(x=[1, 2], y=[10, 12], name='two')]
fig.add_traces(traces)
fig.update_traces(yaxis='y2', selector={'type':'bar'})
fig.show()
```

You could also use your list of traces inside a for loop where you would have a condition for the value of `secondary_y`, that would be even more plotly-idiomatic.

`secondary_y` is not a attribute of plotly traces but rather a convenience attribute used in some functions, so you cannot pass it directly to a trace.